# ThreadPoolExecutor preserves Thread-Local Data between iterations?

Tags: python, python-multithreading, thread-local-storage

I have noticed that if I use ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) to run a function 10 times, the Thread-Local Data is maintained between iterations as if Threads are re-used. I have the following very basic code to test:

```
import time
import uuid
import threading
import concurrent.futures

thread_data = threading.local()

def conc_func(i):
   if not hasattr(thread_data, 'x'):
      thread_data.x = uuid.uuid4()
      print('Setting Thread Data: ', end='')
   else:
      print('Reading Thread Data: ', end='')
   print(thread_data.x)
   time.sleep(1)

def conc_pool():
   with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
      _ = executor.map(conc_func, range(10))

if __name__ == '__main__':
   conc_pool()
```

If I run this code, I get the following output

```
Setting Thread Data: e0101c90-1de7-4c5c-8358-05c6e5b5c89f
Setting Thread Data: 34d1c796-d9e0-4000-a560-2b0d0da47fb4
Setting Thread Data: 2a62e83e-0945-40d4-8af5-e5e77ee9531f
Setting Thread Data: b9bf8871-ea9d-4dca-88d2-c8916ff47e5d
Setting Thread Data: 961a7725-9ebb-4711-81c9-253ddc1c9c80
Reading Thread Data: e0101c90-1de7-4c5c-8358-05c6e5b5c89f
Reading Thread Data: 34d1c796-d9e0-4000-a560-2b0d0da47fb4
Reading Thread Data: 2a62e83e-0945-40d4-8af5-e5e77ee9531f
Reading Thread Data: b9bf8871-ea9d-4dca-88d2-c8916ff47e5d
Reading Thread Data: 961a7725-9ebb-4711-81c9-253ddc1c9c80
```

As you can see there are only 5 unique UUIDs (same as number of unique workers). Because I assign max 5 workers, but pass an iterable with 10 elements, each worker processes two iterations. However, what surprised me is that Thread-Local Data instance is shared between iterations, while I expected it to be CLEAN on every run.

Is there a way to automatically clean-up an instance of Local-Thread Data or should we take care of this cleaning ourselves at the end of the iteration?

Comment: " the Thread-Local Data is maintained between iterations as if Threads are re-used." Yes, that's precisely what is happening, *that is the whole point of a thread pool*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you. it does make sense now.

Answer (score 2):

A thread pool reuses threads, that's the whole point. Any thread-local data is attached to a thread. It will stay with the thread as long as it is alive, and it won't clean itself. You have to do it manually.

That being said my advice is to completely avoid thread-local storage. I am yet to see a case where it is necessary and you cannot simply pass data as argument(s). Maybe except when you already deal with a badly designed code. The drawback is that it is hard to debug and is a hard dependency, e.g. if you ever want to switch to say single threaded, async code then you'll again have a problem, just like now when you reuse threads instead of spawning a new thread each time.

Comment: Thanks, so basically Thread Local Data is kind of a global variable available to a Thread's scope. In which case it does make sense not to use them.

Comment: @YakuzaUA exacfly.

Comment: "I am yet to see a case where it is necessary and you cannot simply pass data as argument(s)."


I'm trying to make a parallel downloader, and I want it to re-use an HTTP connection (session); 1 session per thread.  I don't see any easy way of passing that in to the function.

Comment: @Endlisnis it is not exactly clear what you are doing. My general advice is to create and pass around a connection pool.

Comment: @freakish: Good point.  A connection pool would satisfy my requirements, but since I know that my code already only connects to a single server per thread (by design), each thread only needs a single connection.